# Programmatically opening Google Maps

Tags: google-chrome, shell32.dll

I have a little feature in my apps that lets a user click a button to map an address. Probably done in bunches and bunches of apps out there. And I don't know if this is the right forum, but . . . I simply build the appropriate string and use ShellExecute (in Shell32.dll) to open the browser. So the URL I build might be https://www.google.com/maps/place/8000+Avalon+Blvd,+Alpharetta,+GA+30009

It worked in the past with Chrome, but yesterday I discovered that it is not working and, in fact, craps out Chrome completely. After it tries to display the page, but then gives an error message (Error code: STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN), I can't get any page to come up, even when I just type in ibm.com or something. But I can copy the URL (leaving off the extra stuff Chrome or Maps is trying to add, which seems to be mainly GPS coordinates), close Chrome, reopen it, then paste in the URL and it works perfectly. I have confirmed that what I originally use as the URL to open Chrome is the EXACT same thing I'm putting in manually. It works when done manually, but fails when done programmatically. I switched my default browser to Bing and the exact same command works like a charm. I also noted that it does seem to work if Chrome is already running, but if it has to be started, then I get the error. Anybody have any ideas why using ShellExecute would fail and only on Chrome (have not tested FireFox or any other, yet).

Comment: What if you rename the folder Default in your local appdata to give Chrome a new profile? May be that your Chrome's profile is somehow corrupt or maybe an extension is at fault. If a new profile works, then you know its something in your profile. If it doesn't, then its something in Chrome or your computer.

Comment: What kind of environment is your app running in? (All of it gets inherited by the Chrome process!) Is it in a 'job' object? Is UWP involved somehow?

Comment: LPChip - I'll try with a new profile. Still, odd that it works when Chrome is already running. The default profile - I have two - always seems to be the last one closed.

Comment: u1686_grawity - none of that. It's just a regular Windows app using a standard Windows feature.